# Getting $_GET values not working

Tags: php, javascript, get

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
<!-- Code within Head Tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("#loading").hide();       
    })
</script>
<!-- Code within Head Tag -->

<style type="text/css">
/* Document Styles */

#wrapper{
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    background:#CCC;
}
.desc{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:800px;
    text-align:left;
}

/* Loadign Div Style */
#loading{
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:7px 0 0 0;
    font:bold 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>

 </head>
 <body>



<!-- Loading Div -->
<div id="loading">
    Fetching Hotels, please wait..
    <img src="loading.gif" alt="loading.." />
</div>
<!-- Loading Div -->

<select name="month">
    <option value="1">January
    <option value="2">February
    <option value="3">March
    <option value="4">April
    <option value="5">May
    <option value="6">June
    <option value="7">July
    <option value="8">August
    <option value="9">September
    <option value="10">October
    <option value="11">November
    <option value="12">December
</select>
<select name="day">
    <option value="1">1
    <option value="2">2
    <option value="3">3
    <option value="4">4
    <option value="5">5
    <option value="6">6
    <option value="7">7
    <option value="8">8
    <option value="9">9
    <option value="10">10
    <option value="11">11
    <option value="12">12
    <option value="13">13
    <option value="14">14
    <option value="15">15
    <option value="16">16
    <option value="17">17
    <option value="18">18
    <option value="19">19
    <option value="20">20
    <option value="21">21
    <option value="22">22
    <option value="23">23
    <option value="24">24
    <option value="25">25
    <option value="26">26
    <option value="27">27
    <option value="28">28
    <option value="29">29
    <option value="30">30
    <option value="31">31
</select>
<select name="year">
    <option value="2012">2012
    <option value="2013">2013
    <option value="2014">2014
</select>

<?php
// specify url of xml file
$url = "http://xmlfeed.laterooms.com/index.aspx?aid=1000&rtype=4&kword=".$_GET['title']."&sdate=".$_GET['year']."-".$_GET['month']."-".$_GET['day']."&nights=2&orderby=price&sortorder=asc";
// get xml file contents
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

// loop begins
foreach($xml->hotel as $hotel)
{
// begin new paragraph
echo "<p>";
echo "<img src=".$hotel->images." height=100 width=100><br/>";
echo "<strong>Hotel Name:</strong> ".$hotel->hotel_name."<br/>";
echo "<strong>Hotel City:</strong> ".$hotel->hotel_city."<br/>";
echo "<strong>Hotel County:</strong> ".$hotel->hotel_county."<br/>";
echo "<strong>Prices From:</strong> &pound;".$hotel->prices_from."<br/>";
echo "<strong>Hotel Link:</strong><a href=".$hotel->hotel_link.">click here</a><br/>";
echo "<strong>Miles from ".$_GET['title']."</strong> ".$hotel->hotel_distance."<br/>";
echo "</p>";
// end paragraph
}
// loop ends

?>




<form method="GET"><input type=text name=title><input type=submit></form> 


 </body>
</html>
```

When removing the date option the script works fine. I think ive got an issue with multiple ".$_GET varibles. I have added the name to every date option with no success.. Im kind of new so dont be too hard on me

Comment: Why do you post CSS and all those things. They are indeed not required in this context.

Comment: Considder `<?php for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++) echo "\t<option value=\"$i\">$i\r\n"; ?>` to generate all those days automagically...

Answer (score 2):

The date fields are not within the `<form>...</form>` tags, so they are not being passed into the query string that $_GET gathers it's data from.

Comment: Thankyou! fixed! all data needs to be in the form tags you described, again thanks

Answer (score 0):

The *month*, *day* and *year* selects are separated from the form. That's why only the *text* input is transmitted when you submit the form.